# How to make a button stay on imageView specific point even if zooming in or out in java android studio?

Tags: android, button, imageview, scrollview, zooming

I am trying to make a imageView that will fill the whole screen and on the image view I want to fix a button to specific location on the imageView but when I zoom in or out the location of the button is changing.

I used a Library that doing the zooming in and out for me instead of using scrollViews.

This is my code:

````
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#aaaaaa"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    tools:context=".JewishCemeteryActivity">

    <com.ortiz.touchview.TouchImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/cemetery"
        android:id="@+id/imageV"
        tools:ignore="NestedWeights,SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="13dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="208dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="111dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="501dp"
        android:id="@+id/graveBtn"
        android:background="@drawable/grave_icon" />

</RelativeLayout>```

I tried a lot of options but I didn't get close, please help me!
````